# jgrapht class in jgrapht that will allow me to construct a graph dynamically

Tags: java, jgrapht

I'm  looking for a class in `jgrapht` that will allow me to construct a graph 
dynamically and  generate  new edge  in  the given graph  at run
 time based on  branch of the algorithm .
 I need to implements the  algorithm branch & bound 
 I saw this class `ListenableDirectedWeightedGraph`

Is it possible to add edges to a graph through the use of a loop
 with `ListenableDirectedWeightedGraph` ?

Answer (score 0):

I build my graph with following code:

```
private void fillGraph(Tree tree, Graph<Vertex, Edge> graph)
{
    Vertex root = tree.getRootVertex();
    for (Edge edge : root.getEdges())
        addEdge(edge, graph);
}

private void addEdge(Edge edge, Graph<Vertex, Edge> graph)
{
    Vertex source = edge.getSource();
    Vertex target = edge.getTarget();
    if (!graph.containsVertex(source))
        graph.addVertex(source);
    graph.addVertex(target);
    graph.addEdge(source, target, edge);
    if (!target.getEdges().isEmpty())
        for (Edge e: target.getEdges())
            addEdge(e, graph);
}
```